# Chrome extension to swap two css stylesheet files

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that allows the user to change the CSS of a page by switching between two css files. This is my first Chrome extension and I'm very noob programming javascript and I'm not sure what I'm doing. I hope you can help me to make this work correctly.

This is the manifest.json:

```
    {
    "name": "Scorm Cleaner",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Limpia temarios de ASIR Online!",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "images/get_started128.png"
      }

    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

And this is the popup.html:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="ChangeCSS" href="ScormCleaner.css">Style 1</button>
    <button id="ChangeCSS" href="ScormQuestions.css">Style 2</button>

</body>
</html>
```

And popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("ChangeCSS").addEventListener("click", handler);
});


function handler() {
  document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href');
}
```

This is and image of the popup working on Chrome:

[Popup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYcIA.png)

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure they have an example extension that does exactly this

Comment: I searched and searched but I have not found anything like that, that's why I decided to ask :/

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the office "[Getting Started](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)" tutorial by google as it does something very similar and is a good resource for starters.

You should inject a  element to the page, just before the  tag to make sure that your style will be used. When one of the buttons is pressed you change the content or the style or remove the current one and add a new one.

Comment: That tutorial was my starting point, which does something similar but only changes the background color. Precisely what I want to do is what you are telling me what I should do, but I do not know how to do it and that is why I ask for help.